# Derivative of a convolution integral of the following type?

Tags: differential-equations, integration, convolution, wave-equation

I'm looking to find the derivative of a convolution integral of the following form:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dr}((G(r,t)*f(t)) = \frac{d}{dr} (\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(r,t-\tau)f(\tau) d\tau)
\end{equation}.

Here, $G(r,t)$ is the 2D free space Greens function for the wave equation defined as: 
$ G(r,t) =\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{H(t-r/c)}{\sqrt{t^2 - r^2/c^2}}$, where $H$ is a Heaviside and c is the wave speed constant. And $f(t)$ is a smooth function, I currently have let $f(t) = e^{-\alpha(t-t0)^2}$, ($\alpha$ is constant) and have computed the convolution integral numerically,

\begin{equation}
G(r,t)*f(t) = \int_{0}^{max(0,tn-r/c)} \frac{e^{-\alpha(\tau-t0)^2}}{\sqrt{(t-\tau)^2 - r^2/c^2}}d\tau.
\end{equation}

I was wondering if i could compute the derivative of the above convolution integral as $\frac{dG(r,t)}{dr}*f(t)$, then complete the convolution integral numerically as before but with $\frac{dG}{dr}$ or if there are some complications im not taking into account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the derivative of $\partial G/\partial r$ has a delta function contribution $\delta(t-r/c)(t^2-r^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$, which diverges.

Comment: So perhaps, using a finite difference method to solve this problem would be better.

Comment: if it diverges, then the finite difference method will not converge; there is no meaningful answer, I'm afraid.